# where is executable after compiling curl?

Tags: curl

I just compiled curl from source by cloning the repo from here https://github.com/curl/curl and running the following commands:

```
sudo ./buildconf
sudo ./configure --with-libssh2
sudo make
```

Now I can't find where the executable is!  Or what to do to finish the install.  This is all it says to do in the GIT-INFO file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated: you almost never need to use `sudo` for `configure` or `make` - using it in these steps can (in theory) expose to unnecessary security risks and, most importantly, create a lot of files that only the superuser can delete. OTOH, you generally need `sudo` for `make install` (as it generally has to write to system locations).

Comment: it's in `src/curl`

Comment: Thanks, nos.  From within that folder, I can run ./curl -V and I get what I expect.  But when I try copying that file to /usr/bin, I get the following when I run the command "curl": /usr/bin/curl: error: '/usr/bin/.libs/curl' does not exist
This script is just a wrapper for curl.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861352/path-issue-after-compiling-curl